# How to adjust Chart.js height according to datasets size. Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, chart.js

I'm building an app in Ionic that gets data from an API and shows on a horizontal chart. But the number of the data is not default, then sometimes the chart height isn't enough

[image: See here]

and

[image: here]

and I have issues to make the horizontal chart to be auto adjust on the height. I've already tried to set `height: auto`, but chart.js sets a default height.

My HTML:

```
<div class="chart-container" >
    <canvas #barCanvas></canvas>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.chart-container{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 110vh;
    width: 80vw;
}
```

My JS

```
private loadChart(){

var backgroundColor = [];

if (this.barChart) {
    this.barChart.destroy();
}
for (let x = 0; x < this.servicos.length; x ++) {
    backgroundColor[x] = this.randomColor();        
}


this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: this.temp.labels,
        datasets: [{                
            label:this.consulta.Unidade,
            data: this.temp.valores,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            borderWidth: 0                
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

});
```

}

**[UPDATE 1]** I tried to change the `height` values by comparing the size of the table before create it. It worked, but I have a filter that make a new request and build a new chart, but the height property is set to chartjs default values.

```
if(this.servicos.length <= 10){
    document.getElementById("chart-container").style.height = "300px"
}
if(this.servicos.length > 10 ){
    document.getElementById("chart-container").style.height = "900px"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the filter. I was using a modal that was sending values to another new view `this.navCtrl.push(IndicadoresPage, {consulta: consulta});`.
I changed to `this.viewCtrl.dismiss(consulta)` and caught the data with `onDidDismiss()`.

Then I compared the size of the data return and set `chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = 'XXXpx';` according to the data size.